# Alexa custom intent accepts values which are not stored in the possible slot.values that should trigger it

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have an intent that gets triggered if the user asks Alexa to play  one of the radios that I have provided in the JSON file for the slot `{radio}` on the Alexa console. However, if the user asks Alexa to play "random_english_words", the intent works too.
To simplify here's what happens:

```
-User: Alexa play A better radio  
-Alexa: I will play A better radio  
=> Alexa does her job just fine.  
-User: Alexa play what the Movie  
-Alexa: I will play what the Movie
```

Alexa should send an error because "what the  Movie" is not a possible radio name in the `radio_slot` values. But wait this gets even weirder.

```
User: Alexa play aenjaejfn  
Alexa: There was a problem with the requested skill's response
```

Alexa does her job fine since aenjaejfn is NOT a possible radio name in the radio_slot values.

So I have two questions:

1. Aren't intents which use slots supposed to be triggered only if a slot.value provided by the user is valid?
2. Why is Alexa accepting "What the Movie" and not "aenjaejfn" , after all both of them are not radio_name and should not trigger the intent in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you create a custom slot type, a key concept to understand is
>   that this is training data for Alexa’s NLP (natural language
>   processing). The values you provide are NOT a strict enum or array
>   that limit what the user can say. This has two implications
>
> 1) words and phrases not in your slot values will be passed to you,
>
> 2) your code needs to perform any validation you require if what’s said is
>   unknown.

Since you know the acceptable values for that slot, always perform a slot-value validation on your code. In this way when you get something like "aenjaejfn" or something which you dont support, you can always politely respond back like

> "Sorry I didn't understand, can you repeat"

or

> "Sorry we dont have aenjaejfn in our list. can you please select
>   something from [give some samples from your list]"

More info [here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/tx3ihsfqsuf3rqp/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution)

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering if it's the same with Gooogle Home??